# Comparing two arrays depending on the order of id

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have this code and I want to compare depending of the order of id 
this is the code:

```
foreach ($questions as $question) {
    $question_answers = OrderingAnswer::where('question_id', $question->id)
                            ->where('deleted', 0)
                            ->get()
                            ->toArray();

    $question_answer = $request->except('_token', 'test_id');
    $answers = $question_answer[ $question->id];

    foreach ($question_answers as $answer) {
        if ($answer === $answers) {
            $answer_result[] = 1;
        } else {
            $answer_result[] = 0;
        }
    }

    if (in_array(0, $answer_result)) {
        $question_results[$question->id] = 0;
    } else {
        $question_results[$question->id] = 1;
    }

    $answer_result = [];
    $results =  $question_results;
}
```

I have tried `array_diff`, `array_intersect` but wont work, the result of the `dd($answer);` is like this

```
array:5 [▼
  "id" => 239
  "question_id" => 239
  "text" => "something"
  "order" => 1
  "deleted" => 0
]
```

and  the result of the `dd($answers);` is this

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "239"
  1 => "240"
  2 => "241"
  3 => "242"
]
```

Comment: Please post your input `array/collection` along with your expected output

Comment: Shouldn't this `if($answer === $answers) {` be `if($answer->id === $answers)` by the time you want to compare the id?

Comment: $answers is what the user is selecting  array:4 [▼
  0 => "239"
  1 => "240"
  2 => "241"
  3 => "242"
]

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos No that way it will show Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: So the problem is only the order?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos Yea I need a way to compare if the order of arrays is right to be true

Comment: @ylli Sorry but i can't understand what you are trying to accomplish. Could you print the wanted output?

Comment: This is typically the kind of question that I like to answer, but I don't understand what the input data is and what the expected result is.  Please ping me if you can clarify your question.